# Django template- If DateTimeField value taken from Foreignkey passed to a url, an error occurs: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

[image]I'm quite new to django and trying to figure out why I'm getting an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'` when passing a datetime object to a url from a  `DateTimeField()` value thru `ForeignKey`. Here are the sample codes I'm using and trying to pass `last_checked` value from `Scrape` Model.

*model.py*

```
class Site(models.Model):
     ...


class Scrape(models.Model):
     ...
     last_checked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='scrapes')
```

*url.py*

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import views

class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}'  

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


register_converter(DateConverter, 'date')

urlpatterns = [    
    path('task/<pk>/<date:date_scraped>/', views.scrape_data_csv, name='scrape-csv'),
]
```

If I'm passing the value directly from `Scrape` model queryset to the `template` like this. Everything works perfectly!

```
<a href="{% url 'scrape-csv' site.pk scrape.last.last_checked %}" > </a>
```

However if I passed the value to `Site` model queryset thru `ForeignKey`, which is the way I need to have, here I get the error occurs:

```
{% for site in sites %}

    <a href="{% url 'scrape-csv' site.pk site.scrapes.last.last_checked %}" > </a>

{% endfor%}
```

If we checked the values, both the same `datetime` objects:

```
{{ scrape.last.last_checked }} # April 8, 2022, 10:14 a.m.
{{ site.scrapes.last.last_checked }} # April 8, 2022, 10:14 a.m.
```

We can even use the built-in `filter tags` just fine. Example:

```
{{ scrape.last.last_checked | timezone:'US/Eastern'|date:'F d, Y'}} #  April 8, 2022
{{ site.scrapes.last.last_checked | timezone:'US/Eastern'|date:'F d, Y'}} #  April 8, 2022
```

Can someone tell why `site.scrapes.last.last_checked` results to `AttributeError: 'str'...` when it's not a date string?

Comment: Please share the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: @solarissmoke I added a screenshot. Not sure if that's what need

Answer (score 0):

If the given site has no any scrapes `site.scrapes.last == None`, you receive `site.scrapes.last.last_checked` as empty string in template

Comment: My scraping project and its spiders are separate from django project that run independently. All scraped items are well-filtered before they are stored to the database. I already set all the necessary conditions for that. The django project is only being used to render the stored data, which most of the time being fetched thru `$.ajax`. Also, as what you can see on my example, It has a `truthy` string value. Please check on my question again that pertains on passing `datetime` object to the url.